# Tenés un arreglo de objetos con : 'nombre' y 'mesa', creá un objeto con los invitados ordenados por mesa

Tags: javascript

Debo crear un objeto en el cual contenga el nombre de la mesa, y las personas que pertenecen a esa mesa.
No puedo lograr que los nombres se concatenen dentro del array, porque tampoco puedo ubicarlos en un array externo, porque de esa manera se juntarian con el resto de nombres de la otra mesa

```
//Debe verse así:

//{
//     mesa1: [juan, perez, ...],
//     mesa2: [juan, perez, ...]        
//}
```

Aqui esta la lista de invitados:

```
let invitados = [
  {
    nombre: 'javi',
    mesa: 1
  },
  {
    nombre: 'juli',
    mesa: 1
  },
  {
    nombre: 'mica',
    mesa: 2
  },
  {
    nombre: 'nancy',
    mesa: 2
  },
  {
    nombre: 'nacho',
    mesa: 2
  },
  {
    nombre: 'cami',
    mesa: 3
  },
];
```

aqui mi intento por resolverlo:

```
const mesa = (arr) => {
  let mesas = {}
  let array = [];

  arr.forEach(el => {
      mesas[`mesa${el.mesa}`] = [el.nombre];
      mesas[`mesa${el.mesa}`] = [el.nombre];
  })
  console.log(mesas)
}

mesa(invitados)
```

Comment: Alguien que ponga freno a los estudiantes, por dior! Que aprendan a leer un manual! Estamos criando a los "programadores" del futuro...

Comment: pero @julio tiene parte de razón, hoy tengo la sensación que ha habido una invasión de preguntas demasiado elementales, aún así yo prefiero que pregunten a que se fustren y no sepan donde acudir ni sepan buscar aún.  Otra cosa es si usan correctamente el sitio, y en este caso concreto de esta pregunta no tengo queja pues al menos ha puesto el [example] que muchos ni hacen.

Comment: es que es eso @masterguru. No se molestan en leer un manual ni comprender qué hacen. No conocen ni los principios de la lógica. Quieren la respuesta directa para aprobar el TP. Uno intenta ayudar y aportar sus conocimientos pero se pasan y denigran y menosprecian el sitio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se utiliza en estos casos es una función `push()` para poder agregar cosas a un array. Y lo que puedes hacer es una validación para saber si ya se creo la mesa.

```
arr.forEach(el => {
      if(mesas[`mesa${el.mesa}`] == undefined){
          mesas[`mesa${el.mesa}`] = [];
      }
      
      mesas[`mesa${el.mesa}`].push(el.nombre);
  });
```

Entonces si realizas ese cambio en esa parte de tu código ya te aparecerá con todos los invitados sin que se te borre el anterior.

Comment: muchas gracias @Paulo44 , me ah sido de mucha ayuda alguna forma de marcar tu respuesta como correcta? soy nuevo en esto jaja

Comment: Back to black. No leen el [recorrido inicial](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)